# third party search server and their modules for drupal 7

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-modules

I am new to drupal. I did search functionality using drupal core search but it is inefficient.Suggest me any third party search server(like apache solr) and their modules.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of providers on the [Search API Solr Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) modules page.

The [Search API module](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) module can be used with a mysql database backend which gives you the extra features of search api but unfortunatly not the speed of Solr.

Answer (score 0):

You can also always use Google Custom Search:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Custom_Search